# Make a scrolling view that updates as users scroll down

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, feed

I have a database of news feeds that are sorted by time. The users simply needs to view them line by line. The feeds can get pretty large in numbers so I don't want to show them all at one time. I do not want to make a page view either. So I'm thinking if there is a way to show a page's worth of them in the beginning and as the users scroll down, more begin to appear.

I know this is possible since I think facebook does it. But I'm a little confused at the concept. I'm open to using JavaScript/JQuery and HTML, PHP.

Any ideas on the concept behind this? I'm guessing I need a client side script to access the database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would it hurt to google `infinite ajax scroll` before asking?

Comment: There's a good overview/tutorial of how to achieve this here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/

Comment: @MightyPork: `I'm a little confused at the concept` -- it doesn't hurt to Google but when you don't know what to search for that's not really an option.

Comment: @Cory You would get relevant results even with a query like `load more items scroll down`. Google is powerful, and will guess what you want even if your question is lame. Most of the time, anyway. See for yourself: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=javascript+scroll+infinite&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=uw0BUqvjBMvb4QSewYC4DQ#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&channel=fs&fp=f63e5318e3c41b5&psj=1&q=load+more+items+scroll+down&safe=off

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a PHP script which returns the data in JSON when requested by a client-side AJAX call. If you want the results ranked, this should be easily performed in your query.

I have used this jQuery plugin many times, the examples are plentiful:
[DataTables](https://datatables.net/)